# How can I monitor Lambda runtime including API Gateway overhead per function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-serverless, aws-sam

Considering the following CloudWatch alert on an API Gateway:

```
LatencyAlarmP90:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Condition: Production
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: latency P90 is lower then 1.5 sec
      AlarmName: FooApiP90LatencyAlarm
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      ExtendedStatistic: "p90"
      Period: 300
      MetricName: "Latency"
      DatapointsToAlarm: 5
      EvaluationPeriods: 5
      Threshold: 1500
      Namespace: AWS/ApiGateway
      Dimensions:
        - Name: ApiName
          Value: !Sub "bar"
      AlarmActions:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "foo"
      OKActions:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub foo"
```

If this alert triggers, I have no way of knowing which specific route triggered it (multiple lambdas are on the same API Gateway).

I was thinking about monitoring each Lambda instead.

**If I monitor a specific Lambda latency does it include API Gateway latency? (Cold starts) or only run time?**

**If not, is there a way to monitor a specific route/Lambda including API Gateway latency?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I monitor a specific Lambda latency, does it include API Gateway latency?

No.

The `Duration` performance metric does not include any API Gateway latency & is only Lambda function run time rounded up to the nearest millisecond as per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-types).

---

> If not, is there a way to monitor a specific route/Lambda including API Gateway latency?

Per route yes, per Lambda no.

For a metric that also includes API Gateway overhead, use the [`Latency`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html#api-gateway-metrics) metric for API GW.

Per Lambda function is not a supported [dimension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html#api-gateway-metricdimensions) to assign to the metric and thus filter by but you can achieve the end result by using various other dimensions - including route - to filter this down.

Inevitably, you will need more alarms if the same Lambda function is responsible for multiple routes.

You will have to filter down your alarm by:

- Method
- ApiId & Stage
- Stage
- ApiId
- Api Name

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm already using "latency" and the documentation you referenced is for ApiGateway monitoring exactly as my sample code is, my question is regarding a specific Lamba monitoring

Comment: Updated to clarify - unfortunately, the Lambda function is not a dimension supported for API Gateway currently so you will have to add in a few more alarms based on i.e. method

Comment: do you have an example of how to define a Method? This does not seem to work Dimensions:
        - Name: ApiName
          Value: "myApi"
        - Name: Method
          Value: "/report/payments"

Comment: What does "not work"? Are you using the UI?